# CSS - Keep divs in columns aligned

Tags: css, html, alignment

I tried searching for what I was looking for, but I kept on finding things for css on internal divs.

Anyway, what I am trying to do is have two columns of divs be aligned with oneanother, with the right column always being aligned to the top of  the left column. This is where I am drawing a blank, I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

The size of the left column is dynamic, so I can't use the :height property to keep things in order.

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: can you pls post html and css code?

Comment: If you can put them in a favored order in source code: http://jsfiddle.net/4Ltj2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is, wrap the inline div within a transparent div. For Example:

```
<div class="transparent-container">
    <div class="inline-div">
    </div>
    <div class="inline-div">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

#### [Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5pZM/)

Comment: Yep, used this with @passerby answer and it works:   jsfiddle.net/4Ltj2

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by three ways:

1. Using a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div>div</div></td>
        <td><div>div</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><div>div</div></td>
       <td><div>div</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

2. Using the container div like below:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="left-box">
            Left Box content
        </div>
        <div class="right-box">
            Right Box Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3. Using JS:

Calcuate the height by Js of left-box and  and  then pass that to right-box to maintain the gap.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick very beautyfully:

```
.div1, .div2{
vertical-align:top;
}
.div1{
float:left;
width:70px;
}
.div2{
display: table-cell;
width:200px;
}
.div3{
display:table-cell;
width:200px;
}


<div class='div1'>1</div>
<div class='div2'>ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXY Z</div>
<div class='div1'>2</div><div class='div2'>ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXY Z</div>
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: You can use table

solution 2: using jQuery, get each columns each div and get their height. Then compare the height and set both div in that max height. But i prefer using table to solve this.

Comment: yes, it is. But he has two different column if its in same column then clear float simple can do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it like shown below:

[image]

means in every row you wrap in div, and that div has 2 column divs. clearfloat it after

Answer (score 0):

What I did in a similar situation was - instead of creating two *columns* - building a container for each *row* of 2 divs and float the divs in that container, without floating the container itself. This way the container's height expands to the highest div's height. and the next container will just align under it.

you can have a look at the result and my HTML [here](http://galilee-export.com/about-us/our-team-2/sales/).

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a grid, but simple tables and nested divs forced me to lay out rows at a time. This made it hard to stack columns for a responsive design.

Here's a code pen that uses flexboxes to create grids. The first one lets you specify rows at a time, while the second one lets you specify columns at a time.

https://codepen.io/chaimleib/pen/zPPGgj

HTML:

```
<h2>By row</h2>
<div class="table table3cols">
  <div class="table-cell"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
  <div class="table-cell">Sword named Ice</div>
  <div class="table-cell">No direwolf</div>

  <div class="table-cell"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
  <div class="table-cell">Sword named Longclaw</div>
  <div class="table-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>

  <div class="table-cell"><h3>Arya Stark</h3></div>
  <div class="table-cell">Sword named Needle</div>
  <div class="table-cell">Direwolf: Nymeria</div>
</div>

<h2>By column</h2>

<div class="table table3cols">
  <div style="order:1;" class="table-cell"><h3>Eddard Stark</h3></div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="table-cell">Sword named Ice</div>
  <div style="order:3;" class="table-cell">No direwolf</div>

  <div style="order:1;" class="table-cell"><h3>Jon Snow</h3></div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="table-cell">Sword named Longclaw</div>
  <div style="order:3;" class="table-cell">Direwolf: Ghost</div>

  <div style="order:1;" class="table-cell"><h3>Arya Stark</h3></div>
  <div style="order:2;" class="table-cell">Sword named Needle</div>
  <div style="order:3;" class="table-cell">Direwolf: Nymeria</div>
</div>
```

LESS:

```
/* Variables
================================== */
@bw: 3px;  // border width

/* Tables
================================== */
.table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 0 3em 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.table-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;  // Default to full width
  padding: 0.8em 1.2em;
  overflow: hidden; // Or flex might break
  list-style: none;
  border: solid @bw white; // margins would overflow row and cause early wrapping
  background: fade(slategrey,20%);
  > h1, > h2, > h3, > h4, > h5, > h6 { margin: 0; }
}

/* Table column sizing
================================== */
.table2cols > .table-cell  { width: 50%; }
.table3cols > .table-cell  { width: 33.33%; }
.table4cols > .table-cell  { width: 25%; }

/* Page styling
================================== */

body {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 2em;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin-top: 0; }
```

Credit for the technique goes to Davide Rizzo, whose [article](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-simple-responsive-tables/) also shows spiffy ways to make the design responsive.